# What is the best way to deploy a Java desktop application to multiple platforms?

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java application intended to run on the desktop, which will use Swing for its UI.  I'm familiar with Java Web Start, but have heard that it can be cumbersome and buggy.

What tools are available to make it easier to deploy Java applications to multiple platforms?  I'm particularly looking for freely available tools, or at least tools that are free for use with open source projects.

edit: I should clarify that this is for a peer-to-peer application that will predominantly run in the background, and should (optionally) be able to start automatically on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

edit2: I should further clarify that this app is intended to operate in countries where the government may censor our website.  As such, its important that it can be distributed as a stand-alone file, rather than something that must be downloaded from a known website.

Comment: should just work. you have to do something wrong to break it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java Web Start is currently the best technology for platform independent centrally controlled *distribution* of Java programs.

With the update of JWS in Java 6u10 things were improved quite a bit - previously especially caching was a problem.

We have found that by ensuring unique URL's to the jar files for each new release instead of reusing them, the cache problems almost went away.

Comment: Is Java Web Start suitable for long-running applications (such as a P2P app which runs in the background, and should start automatically)?

Comment: We used Java Web Start in out Desktop Application which went Production Grade with more than 200 clients. So i can say it's the best thing out there right now for Java Desktop Applications, plus the upgrade feature in JavaWS is Awesome.

Comment: Java WebStart is responsible for downloading the application as needed, and to launch it (with a quite restrictive SecurityManager).  When the application is launched the work is essentially done.  Hence it is your applications own responsibility to stay up.  Automatic launching can be done in the startup folder - I have no experience with running java webstart in a Windows service.

Comment: @Abishek, JavaWS wants to update the jars up front at a change which may be inconvenient for the user.  A facility for "Yes, download the update, but let me work on the old release for now" is badly needed.

Comment: I just edited to include another constraint that may be problematic for JWS.

Comment: @sanity, automatic launch normally means "not running as a logged-in user and hence nowhere to show the Swing GUI".

Comment: No, I mean running as a "task tray" application.

Comment: @sanity, "task tray" still requires a user context.

Comment: @sanity, any particular reason you cannot just run a normal bittorrent client?

Comment: @Thorbjørn, a bittorrent client?  What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @sanity, a "peer to peer application" sounds like a bittorrent client.  Or are your needs requiring a different protocol?

Comment: @Thorbjørn, no, its not very particular requirements.  Its an anonymous, decentralized, censorship-resistent micro-blogging platform.

Comment: @sanity, in that case write the program - including the System Tray interface described in http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/ - and then come back.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, what did you mean by "unique url ensuring cache problems"? Does this mean that your .jnlp will contain libraries contained in different directories than previous versions to ensure the latest ones are loaded and not the old ones remaining on the desktop users computer?

Comment: @KimJongWoo, yes.  Do not reuse paths for different versions of the same file - it takes so little to break.

Comment: I thought the caching problem was fixed? I guess not

Comment: @KimJongWoo, it takes so little to break.  All you need is bad timestamps on the server.